# Long press some key in ios is not working

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, ipados

I'm using iPad with Bluetooth keyboard and I find that long press is not recognized, say, I long press "k" and iPad work the same as I just press once. That isn't ideal as I'm trying to ssh and use vim.

Comment: What do you expect a long press to do?

Comment: Do you mean that when you hold the key down, you don't get key repeat?

Comment: Yes, I expect hold key will get key repeat

Answer (score 1):

[The API for apps to be able to detect keys being held on external keyboards is new with iOS 13.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312598/1549818) Apps need to be updated to support this. Contact the developer of the app you’re using to add this.